# Meteor Publication and Subscription fetch all records after use skip and limit

Tags: meteor

We have use publication and subscription with skip and limit in meteor and it fetch all records at client side.

```
Meteor.publish('jobOrders', function(skip, limit) {
  return (jobOrders.find({}, {
    skip: skip,
    limit: limit
  }));
});
Template.templateName.onCreated(function() {
  this.subscribe("jobOrders", 0, 2);
});
Template.templateName.helpers({
  methodName: function() {
    var totalNoOfRecords = jobOrders.find({}).count();
    console.og("records are", totalNoOfRecords);
    return totalNoOfRecords;
  }
});
```

Comment: what is exactly your question/problem with this code?

Comment: @Bhuwan, my question is that why it fetch all records on client side after use of limit.

Answer (score 0):

The reason could be because you have other pub-subs in other templates which are fetching the data from `jobOrders` collection.

Please comment your subscription in your current template and see whether you are still able to fetch the records from this collection. If you are seeing all the records even after commenting the subscription, it should be because of some other subscription.

To overcome this problem, you have to either do one of the following:

- Change the other subscription which is fetching all the records such that the data is available only with in that template by using

  ```
  Template.instance().subscribe()
  ```

  instead of using `Meteor.subscribe()`which will make the data available throughout client side across all templates.
- Filter you records on the client side as well.

  ```
  Template.templateName.helpers({
     methodName: function() {
        var totalNoOfRecords = jobOrders.find({skip:0, limit: 2}).count(); //Filter on the client side
        console.og("records are", totalNoOfRecords);
        return totalNoOfRecords;
     }
  });
  ```

Note: Another possibility could be that you did not remove the insecure package which will automatically publish all the records in all the collection.